How to make multiple processes write to the same file chronically in Python?
I am using multi processes in python, each process executes the same program that reads from some pkl files, which store dictionaries, analyses new data based on these pkl and updates the same pkl files with new results.
Multiprocessing is just used to speed up the execution, ideally they should work as if it was a single process executing a program. That is, these pkl files are updated at every iteration of the loop of running this program.
In practice, they might update these pkl files together, or if process A is reading pkl files while process B is writing into it, resulting A reading corrupted values.
Can anyone help me understand how to solve this proved?

Generally you'd have the multiple processes (or threads) do the time consuming processing and then return the results back to a main or other dedicated process (or thread), which then writes the data sequentially. Queues are useful for collecting the results.

@101 Thank you for your inspiration. All these independent processes (each of them runs on one physical core, so I call it process for now) must also read their common files before their individual iteration.  It’s easier to understand it when we think about a single process doing all the works. It’s a loop. Program reads from files, update the same files. There won’t be conflict in this case. But we have to solve this conflict for multi processes. Or do you think there is other way to do it? They could have their own output files but eventually we need to analyse the sum for the same goal.

Yes, you can have the processes doing the work, but then instead of trying to write the results to a file, they send the results back to a single process (via a queue) that writes all of the files.

@101 thank you very much again. one quick question. Does it mean this extra process run on its own physical core? The total number of cores I use to run simulation is then Number of CPU - 1

Up to you, and your program requirements (e.g. responsive UI vs background app). If the file writes aren't intensive you could have them done by the primary worker process. Probably best to start by benchmarking the reads, processing, and writes to see what you can get away with.

@101 I got your idea and implemented it. Just come back to say thank you.

If it should ideally function like one process, just use one process, or maybe the threading module. There isn’t really much benefit to different processes instead of threads (as far as I know) unless you need ‘threads’ (or forked processes) to create more threads (or forked processes).
One benefit to using the threading module is that you can make a lock for, say, reading some pkl files. It works more-or-less like this:
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock: # put this in a function which is started as a thread.
    # do stuff needing lock
    stuff_needing_lock()
# when another thread has the lock, no other threads can run

Simply do it with threads and locks.
You could also define your own lock class which doesn’t automatically stop other threads, but you could call the .require() method to wait until another thread has released the lock
class lock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.aquired = False
    def aquire(self):
        self.aquired = True
    def require(self):
        while self.aquired:
            pass # do nothing if another thread has aquired the lock.
    def release(self): # don’t call unless you aquired the lock
        self.aquired = False

Excuse my inability to spell aquire and so on.
You could just use a filesystem lock but I don’t know how to do that in python.

The reason why I need multiprocessing specifically is that I am actually using Python to wrap up a hardware simulation environment. The simulation itself is slow, so if I could run multiple copies of independent simulation envrionments, the overall wall clock time is much shorter. These simulations must be completely independent, however, as I mentioned in the question, they would modify and read same pickle files (as if It was, loosely, one process).  Do you think it is better to just let them have their own pickle files and somehow collect them in another process?
